# How to retrieve HANA View comment from HANA Studio

Tags: view, comments, hana, hana-studio

After creating a view in HANA, it is possible to add a comment at the view level, or at the column level with the command :

```
COMMENT ON VIEW "view_name" IS 'view comment';
COMMENT ON COLUMN "view_name"."col_name" IS 'column comment';
```

Column comments are visible from the HANA Studio: 'Open Definition'
[image: Hana Studio ScreenShot]

Can VIEWS comment also be visible in 'Open Definition'?
Views comments can be retrieved with :

```
SELECT comments FROM VIEWS WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'view_name'
```

Also in 'Open Definition', the 'Create statement' of the views omits the statement from COMMENT.
Can this be added with settings?

Executed COMMENT ON COLUMNS/VIEWS
Open Definition from HANA Studio